# Source Code styling trespassing to other parts of the document

Tags: listings

I'm learning LaTex and searching for ways to insert my c# code into a LaTex document, I found this style from github gists, that formats it pretty good, but the font color is still affected outside the code part grabbed from the file, and I can't figure out why this happens. The preamble of my .tex looks like this:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\graphicspath{{images/}}

\definecolor{base0}{RGB}{131,148,150}
\definecolor{base01}{RGB}{88,110,117}
\definecolor{base2}{RGB}{238,232,213}
\definecolor{sgreen}{RGB}{133,153,0}
\definecolor{sblue}{RGB}{38,138,210}
\definecolor{scyan}{RGB}{42,161,151}
\definecolor{smagenta}{RGB}{211,54,130}


\newcommand\digitstyle{\color{smagenta}}
\newcommand\symbolstyle{\color{base01}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ProcessDigit}[1]
{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode\relax%
   {\digitstyle #1}%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}
\makeatother


\lstdefinestyle{solarizedcsharp} {
  language=[Sharp]C,
  frame=lr,
  linewidth=160mm,
  breaklines=true,
  tabsize=2,
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=5pt,
  firstnumber=auto,
  numberstyle=\tiny\ttfamily\color{base0},
  rulecolor=\color{base2},
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\color{base01},
  morecomment=[s][\color{base01}]{/*+}{*/},
  morecomment=[s][\color{base01}]{/*-}{*/},
  morekeywords={  abstract, event, new, struct,
                as, explicit, null, switch,
                base, extern, object, this,
                bool, false, operator, throw,
                break, finally, out, true,
                byte, fixed, override, try,
                case, float, params, typeof,
                catch, for, private, uint,
                char, foreach, protected, ulong,
                checked, goto, public, unchecked,
                class, if, readonly, unsafe,
                const, implicit, ref, ushort,
                continue, in, return, using,
                decimal, int, sbyte, virtual,
                default, interface, sealed, volatile,
                delegate, internal, short, void,
                do, is, sizeof, while,
                double, lock, stackalloc,
                else, long, static,
                enum, namespace, string, var},
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{sgreen},
  showstringspaces=false,
  stringstyle=\color{scyan},
  identifierstyle=\color{sblue},
  extendedchars=true,
  literate=
    {0}{{{\ProcessDigit{0}}}}1
    {1}{{{\ProcessDigit{1}}}}1
    {2}{{{\ProcessDigit{2}}}}1
    {3}{{{\ProcessDigit{3}}}}1
    {4}{{{\ProcessDigit{4}}}}1
    {5}{{{\ProcessDigit{5}}}}1
    {6}{{{\ProcessDigit{6}}}}1
    {7}{{{\ProcessDigit{7}}}}1
    {8}{{{\ProcessDigit{8}}}}1
    {9}{{{\ProcessDigit{9}}}}1
    {\}}{{\symbolstyle{\}}}}1
    {\{}{{\symbolstyle{\{}}}1
    {(}{{\symbolstyle{(}}}1
    {)}{{\symbolstyle{)}}}1
    {=}{{\symbolstyle{$=$}}}1
    {;}{{\symbolstyle{$;$}}}1
    {>}{{\symbolstyle{$>$}}}1
    {<}{{\symbolstyle{$<$}}}1
    {\%}{{\symbolstyle{$\%$}}}1
      {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
  {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
  {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
  {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
  {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
  {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
  {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
  {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
  {ã}{{\~a}}1 {ẽ}{{\~e}}1 {ĩ}{{\~i}}1 {õ}{{\~o}}1 {ũ}{{\~u}}1
  {Ã}{{\~A}}1 {Ẽ}{{\~E}}1 {Ĩ}{{\~I}}1 {Õ}{{\~O}}1 {Ũ}{{\~U}}1
  {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
  {ű}{{\H{u}}}1 {Ű}{{\H{U}}}1 {ő}{{\H{o}}}1 {Ő}{{\H{O}}}1
  {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
  {€}{{\euro}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1 {«}{{\guillemotleft}}1
  {»}{{\guillemotright}}1 {ñ}{{\~n}}1 {Ñ}{{\~N}}1 {¿}{{?`}}1 {¡}{{!`}}1,
}

\lstset{escapechar=@,style=solarizedcsharp}
```

And what happens in the pdf is this:

[image: Before importing the code from the file image]

Becomes this:

[image: After importing the code from the file image]

I would like for the second one to not be affected by the style of the solarized theme of the c# code, but I don't even know why it's being affected in the first place! Here's how I insert the code from the c# file:

```
\subsection{Código}
\lstinputlisting{code/Ejercicio1.cs}

\subsection{Capturas de Pantalla}
```

**Edit:** Here's a test document that shows the error in styling.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{base0}{RGB}{131,148,150}
\definecolor{base01}{RGB}{88,110,117}
\definecolor{base2}{RGB}{238,232,213}
\definecolor{sgreen}{RGB}{133,153,0}
\definecolor{sblue}{RGB}{38,138,210}
\definecolor{scyan}{RGB}{42,161,151}
\definecolor{smagenta}{RGB}{211,54,130}


\newcommand\digitstyle{\color{smagenta}}
\newcommand\symbolstyle{\color{base01}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ProcessDigit}[1]
{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode\relax%
   {\digitstyle #1}%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\lstdefinestyle{solarizedcsharp} {
  language=[Sharp]C,
  frame=lr,
  linewidth=160mm,
  breaklines=true,
  tabsize=2,
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=5pt,
  firstnumber=auto,
  numberstyle=\tiny\ttfamily\color{base0},
  rulecolor=\color{base2},
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\color{base01},
  morecomment=[s][\color{base01}]{/*+}{*/},
  morecomment=[s][\color{base01}]{/*-}{*/},
  morekeywords={  abstract, event, new, struct,
                as, explicit, null, switch,
                base, extern, object, this,
                bool, false, operator, throw,
                break, finally, out, true,
                byte, fixed, override, try,
                case, float, params, typeof,
                catch, for, private, uint,
                char, foreach, protected, ulong,
                checked, goto, public, unchecked,
                class, if, readonly, unsafe,
                const, implicit, ref, ushort,
                continue, in, return, using,
                decimal, int, sbyte, virtual,
                default, interface, sealed, volatile,
                delegate, internal, short, void,
                do, is, sizeof, while,
                double, lock, stackalloc,
                else, long, static,
                enum, namespace, string, var},
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{sgreen},
  showstringspaces=false,
  stringstyle=\color{scyan},
  identifierstyle=\color{sblue},
  extendedchars=true,
  literate=
    {0}{{{\ProcessDigit{0}}}}1
    {1}{{{\ProcessDigit{1}}}}1
    {2}{{{\ProcessDigit{2}}}}1
    {3}{{{\ProcessDigit{3}}}}1
    {4}{{{\ProcessDigit{4}}}}1
    {5}{{{\ProcessDigit{5}}}}1
    {6}{{{\ProcessDigit{6}}}}1
    {7}{{{\ProcessDigit{7}}}}1
    {8}{{{\ProcessDigit{8}}}}1
    {9}{{{\ProcessDigit{9}}}}1
    {\}}{{\symbolstyle{\}}}}1
    {\{}{{\symbolstyle{\{}}}1
    {(}{{\symbolstyle{(}}}1
    {)}{{\symbolstyle{)}}}1
    {=}{{\symbolstyle{$=$}}}1
    {;}{{\symbolstyle{$;$}}}1
    {>}{{\symbolstyle{$>$}}}1
    {<}{{\symbolstyle{$<$}}}1
    {\%}{{\symbolstyle{$\%$}}}1
      {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
  {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
  {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
  {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
  {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
  {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
  {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
  {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
  {ã}{{\~a}}1 {ẽ}{{\~e}}1 {ĩ}{{\~i}}1 {õ}{{\~o}}1 {ũ}{{\~u}}1
  {Ã}{{\~A}}1 {Ẽ}{{\~E}}1 {Ĩ}{{\~I}}1 {Õ}{{\~O}}1 {Ũ}{{\~U}}1
  {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
  {ű}{{\H{u}}}1 {Ű}{{\H{U}}}1 {ő}{{\H{o}}}1 {Ő}{{\H{O}}}1
  {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
  {€}{{\euro}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1 {«}{{\guillemotleft}}1
  {»}{{\guillemotright}}1 {ñ}{{\~n}}1 {Ñ}{{\~N}}1 {¿}{{?`}}1 {¡}{{!`}}1,
}

\lstset{escapechar=@,style=solarizedcsharp}

\begin{document}
    \section{This appears normal}
    \blindtext
    \section{Code Here}
    %I use the \lstinputlisting{filename} command but the problem appears with this one as well, only lstinline doesn't have this styling problem.
    \begin{lstlisting}
        var a = "Dummy Code!"
    \end{lstlisting}

    \section{This has different styling!}
    \blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a complete minimal document that shows your error and that we can run to investigate?

Comment: Great suggestion, now it has a test document that reporudces the error, just copy it and run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining `\symbolstyle` as a switch command. That means that after `\smybolstyle` all text in the current group gets a new colour like in

```
some text {more text \color{red} new colour} old colour
```

But then you are using `\smybolstyle` not as a switch, but instead as a macro with text argument (`hello \symbolsstle{new colour} old colour` e.g. in

```
{\}}{{\symbolstyle{\}}}}1
```

you use `\symbolstyle{\}}`. You can see how that goes wrong if you try

```
some text more text \color{red}{new colour} NOT old colour
```

So your definition of `\symbolstyle` should be different: You want it to behave like a text command that takes an argument and only applies to that argument.

You could say

```
\newcommand\symbolstyle[1]{{\color{blue}#1}}
```

to keep the colour change local with the group started and ended by the additional curly braces or use `\textcolor` either with implicit arguments

```
\newcommand\symbolstyle{\textcolor{blue}}
```

or explicit arguments

```
\newcommand\symbolstyle[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
```

This works because `\textcolor` is defined as text command that only colours its text argument.

---

Your use of `\digitstyle`, which is defined analogous to `\symbolstyle`, is fine, because in

```
{\digitstyle #1}%
```

you use that it as a switch and not a text macro.

---

Your MWE with a fixed definition of `\symbolstyle`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{base0}{RGB}{131,148,150}
\definecolor{base01}{RGB}{88,110,117}
\definecolor{base2}{RGB}{238,232,213}
\definecolor{sgreen}{RGB}{133,153,0}
\definecolor{sblue}{RGB}{38,138,210}
\definecolor{scyan}{RGB}{42,161,151}
\definecolor{smagenta}{RGB}{211,54,130}


\newcommand\digitstyle{\color{smagenta}}
\newcommand\symbolstyle{\textcolor{base01}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ProcessDigit}[1]
{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode\relax%
   {\digitstyle #1}%
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\lstdefinestyle{solarizedcsharp} {
  language=[Sharp]C,
  frame=lr,
  linewidth=160mm,
  breaklines=true,
  tabsize=2,
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=5pt,
  firstnumber=auto,
  numberstyle=\tiny\ttfamily\color{base0},
  rulecolor=\color{base2},
  basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
  commentstyle=\color{base01},
  morecomment=[s][\color{base01}]{/*+}{*/},
  morecomment=[s][\color{base01}]{/*-}{*/},
  morekeywords={  abstract, event, new, struct,
                as, explicit, null, switch,
                base, extern, object, this,
                bool, false, operator, throw,
                break, finally, out, true,
                byte, fixed, override, try,
                case, float, params, typeof,
                catch, for, private, uint,
                char, foreach, protected, ulong,
                checked, goto, public, unchecked,
                class, if, readonly, unsafe,
                const, implicit, ref, ushort,
                continue, in, return, using,
                decimal, int, sbyte, virtual,
                default, interface, sealed, volatile,
                delegate, internal, short, void,
                do, is, sizeof, while,
                double, lock, stackalloc,
                else, long, static,
                enum, namespace, string, var},
  keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{sgreen},
  showstringspaces=false,
  stringstyle=\color{scyan},
  identifierstyle=\color{sblue},
  extendedchars=true,
  literate=
    {0}{{{\ProcessDigit{0}}}}1
    {1}{{{\ProcessDigit{1}}}}1
    {2}{{{\ProcessDigit{2}}}}1
    {3}{{{\ProcessDigit{3}}}}1
    {4}{{{\ProcessDigit{4}}}}1
    {5}{{{\ProcessDigit{5}}}}1
    {6}{{{\ProcessDigit{6}}}}1
    {7}{{{\ProcessDigit{7}}}}1
    {8}{{{\ProcessDigit{8}}}}1
    {9}{{{\ProcessDigit{9}}}}1
    {\}}{{\symbolstyle{\}}}}1
    {\{}{{\symbolstyle{\{}}}1
    {(}{{\symbolstyle{(}}}1
    {)}{{\symbolstyle{)}}}1
    {=}{{\symbolstyle{$=$}}}1
    {;}{{\symbolstyle{$;$}}}1
    {>}{{\symbolstyle{$>$}}}1
    {<}{{\symbolstyle{$<$}}}1
    {\%}{{\symbolstyle{$\%$}}}1
      {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
  {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
  {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
  {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
  {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
  {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
  {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
  {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
  {ã}{{\~a}}1 {ẽ}{{\~e}}1 {ĩ}{{\~i}}1 {õ}{{\~o}}1 {ũ}{{\~u}}1
  {Ã}{{\~A}}1 {Ẽ}{{\~E}}1 {Ĩ}{{\~I}}1 {Õ}{{\~O}}1 {Ũ}{{\~U}}1
  {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
  {ű}{{\H{u}}}1 {Ű}{{\H{U}}}1 {ő}{{\H{o}}}1 {Ő}{{\H{O}}}1
  {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
  {€}{{\euro}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1 {«}{{\guillemotleft}}1
  {»}{{\guillemotright}}1 {ñ}{{\~n}}1 {Ñ}{{\~N}}1 {¿}{{?`}}1 {¡}{{!`}}1,
}

\lstset{escapechar=@,style=solarizedcsharp}

\begin{document}
    \section{This appears normal}
    \blindtext
    \section{Code Here}
    \begin{lstlisting}
        var a = "Dummy Code!" 1234
    \end{lstlisting}

    \section{This has different styling!}
    \blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image: Correctly highlighted code. The following text remains in the correct colour.]

Of course another solution would have been to keep the definition of `\symbolstyle` and fix the *usage* of the macro. But that would have required more changes to the MWE.

Comment: Thank you! You really helped a newbie here, thanks for the explanation too!